# Ionic layout structure to be followed when developing application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I have started learning Ionic. I have some question regarding how the layout can be structured better for full screen app.

I have developed an Android version (native) app and client asked me to do in hybrid. The Android app was auto adjusting to the screen height (login screen) and no scroll was coming. But if I use the hybrid app the scroll bar coming and 75% screen visible and need to scroll down. Should I follow any best practices to achieve this? Also why we need to use SCSS is it can be used to write resolution based CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to see the login page that you are working on, you could show a screenshot, but... we can say that you should adjust the css and the content page to fit in a screen without scrolling. Due to the android screen fragmentation, you could need to write some specific css rules for each screen size's group, but this depends to the design's page that you are trying to build.

Here an article about [Css Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Here an useful article about [Android Screen Fragmentation](http://rustyshelf.org/2014/07/08/the-android-screen-fragmentation-myth/)

Also keep in mind that you can disable the scrolling for a specific view:

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
   ...
   ... 
</ion-content>
```